# Dynamic resources in admin panel with Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel-nova

I have a taxonomy system for a Laravel application I'm working on, as we needed more flexibility than the usual category/tag systems. Taxonomy models look something like this:

- id
- name

While the topic models look something like this:

- id
- taxonomy_id
- name
- description

Projects then have a many-to-many relationship with topics.

Now, the project is using Nova for the admin, and I've registered the Topic and Taxonomy models in the usual way, so from the admin one can create a Taxonomy, and then create Topics within that taxonomy. However, that's not exactly the behaviour I'd ideally want. I'd prefer it if I could define a Taxonomy, then have that taxonomy dynamically appear in the admin.

For example, if I create a new taxonomy in the admin called **Sectors**, I'd then see **Sectors** appear as a registered resource. These would still be Topic instances under the hood, but would be presented as Sectors. If I then created a **Type of Work** taxonomy, that would then be added dynamically as a registered resource too.

After digging through the Nova docs I haven't found a way to achieve this in the admin. Can anyone suggest a possible route to achieve this?